# OFFSET with Where Clause SQL Query

Tags: sql

I am facing one weird issue with OFFSET (using skip in linq). When I use where clause and filter null values, offset returns records in wrong order.

```
select * from ExpectedApplication where ApplicationId is null
order by PaymentDate desc 
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY 

select * from ExpectedApplication where ApplicationId is null
order by PaymentDate desc 
OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Output is :

[image]

Because of this issue my pagination result is returning incorrect data. Please help. Many thanks in advance.

Regards,
Vivek

Comment: Show `PaymentDate`  column with your images: `select PaymentDate, * from ExpectedApplication where ApplicationId is null
order by PaymentDate desc 
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY `

Comment: It is likely that the problematic IDs have the same `PaymentDate`, and so get sorted incorrectly; try adding `Id` to the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Though it solves the problem but I just want to order by date pnly.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (select * from ExpectedApplication where ApplicationId is null) as tbl
order by PaymentDate desc
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

You can try like this (using sub query)
It is working for me.